# Row matrix minus vector with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am mainly R user, but I would like to learn **Rcpp** to improve my coding(speed). So I start out playing around with **C++** and **Rcpp**, I thought I’d just try to write the following simple function which takes the row of matrix, (i.e first row) and deduct a vector from it (m[1,]-vec).

I know this sound silly and simple but I am not able to get it work.

> code <- '
>    arma::mat beta =
>   Rcpp::as(beta_);
>    arma::vec y =
>   Rcpp::as(y_);
>    arma::rowvec S= beta.row(0);
>   arma::vec d = S - y;
>    return Rcpp::wrap(d);
>   '
>  fun <-
>   cxxfunction(signature(beta_ ="matrix",y_="numeric"),code,
>   plugin="RcppArmadillo")
>  m <- matrix(1:9,3)
>  vec <-
>   c(1,2,5)
>  fun(m,vec)
>   **Error in fun(m, vec) :**
>
> in R this wil be done as,
>   m[1,]-vec
>   0 2 2

Comment: it would have been nice to follow up on [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9154383/471093)

Answer (score 3):

```
library(RcppArmadillo)
library(inline)
code <- '
arma::mat beta = Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(beta_);
arma::rowvec y = Rcpp::as<arma::rowvec>(y_);
arma::rowvec S= beta.row(0);
arma::rowvec d = S - y;
return Rcpp::wrap(d);
'
fun <- cxxfunction(signature(beta_ ="matrix",y_="numeric"),code, plugin="RcppArmadillo")
m <- matrix(1:9,3)
vec <- c(1,2,5)
fun(m,vec)
```

Comment: Thank you baptiste. Rgarding the preivous question I am still trying to workout the loop...in either case (Fail/succeed)  I will post it online.