# R: Is it possible to vectorise / speed-up this double loop?

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

This is a high-level, general question. There are some similar ones around with different, and more concise, examples. Perhaps it cannot be answered. `conn` is a matrix.

```
     for (i in 2:dim(conn)[1]) {
        for (j in 2:dim(conn)[1]) {
          if ((conn[i, 1] == conn[1, j]) & conn[i, 1] != 0) {
              conn[i, j] <- 1
              conn[j, i] <- 1
              }
              else {
                conn[i, j] <- 0
                conn[j, i] <- 0
                }
           }
      }
```

This comes straight out of `cluscomp` from the clusterCons package.

My question is simply: is it possible to speed up the loop or to vectorise it?
As an R beginner, I cannot see it and don't want to end up with frustration because it may not be possible.
I'll accept any answer that can say yes or no and hint towards the potential amount of effort involved.

Comment: Please post sample data and expected results. Also, try to describe in words what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, it is very likely that a very fast solution can be found in this case. I'll see if I can cook something up quickly.

Comment: Will the matrix `conn` always be symmetric?

Comment: Do you mean "cluscomp"? There's no conscomp in clusterCons.

Comment: Looking at the cluscomp code, it seems like (a) this is referring to cluscomp, yeah, and (b) the data is always symmetric. Hmm, I have an idea....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-matrixy solution - should be pretty damn fast, assuming conn is non-negative and symmetric...

```
connmake = function(conn){
  ordering = order(conn[,1])
  breakpoints = which(diff(conn[ordering,1]) != 0)
  if (conn[ordering[1], 1] != 0){
    breakpoints = c(1, breakpoints + 1, nrow(conn) + 1)
  } else {
    breakpoints = c(breakpoints + 1, nrow(conn) +1)
  }
  output = matrix(0, nrow(conn), nrow(conn))

  for (i in 1:(length(breakpoints) - 1)){
    output[ ordering[breakpoints[i]:(breakpoints[i+1] -1)],
        ordering[breakpoints[i]:(breakpoints[i+1] -1)]] =  1
  }
  output[,1] = conn[,1]
  output[1,] = conn[,1]
  output
}
```

Some test code using earlier benchmarking. (Original code is implemented as `orig()` , `f2()` is earlier suggestion.)

```
size = 2000
conn  = matrix(0, size, size)
conn[1,] = sample( 1:20, size, replace = T)
conn[,1] = conn[1,]

system.time(orig(conn) -> out1)
#user  system elapsed 
#20.54    0.00   20.54 
system.time(f2(conn) -> out2)
#user  system elapsed
#0.39    0.02    0.41 
system.time(connmake(conn) -> out3)
#user  system elapsed 
#0.02    0.00    0.01 
identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
identical(out1, out3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Note that f2 actually fails for conn containing 0, but not my problem, eh? conn with negative values can be dealt with simply by e.g. increasing the relevant values by a safe offset. Non-symmetric conn will require more thought, but should be doable...

The general lesson is that sort is fast compared to pairwise comparison. Pairwise comparison is O(N^2), while the slowest sort algorithm in R is O(N^4/3). Once the data is sorted, comparisons become trivial.

Comment: Also, there's probably a way to get rid of that loop in there if it's still not fast enough, but I doubt it's worth it.

Comment: +1 for the nice algo. Thanks for pointing out I forgot the `0` case, I have fixed my code.

Comment: I bow to your R expertise. In fact f2 looks very promising, very fast, but wasn't working as expected, hence, no "answer" yet. Will have a go with connmake tomorrow morning. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure what objects go in and out, but I had to add `rownames(output) <- row.names(x)`and `colnames(output) <- row.names(x)`to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would have written it, using `outer` as a substitute for the double loop. Note that it is still doing more computations than needed,  but is certainly faster. I have assumed `conn` is a square matrix.

The original code:

```
f1 <- function(conn) {
   for (i in 2:dim(conn)[1]) {
      for (j in 2:dim(conn)[1]) {
         if ((conn[i, 1] == conn[1, j]) & conn[i, 1] != 0) {
            conn[i, j] <- 1
            conn[j, i] <- 1
         } else {
            conn[i, j] <- 0
            conn[j, i] <- 0
         }
      }
   }
   return(conn)
}
```

My suggestion:

```
f2 <- function(conn) {
   matches <- 1*outer(conn[-1,1], conn[1,-1], `==`)
   matches[conn[-1,1] == 0, ] <- 0
   ind <- upper.tri(matches)
   matches[ind] <- t(matches)[ind]
   conn[-1,-1] <- matches
   return(conn)
}
```

Some sample data:

```
set.seed(12345678)
conn <- matrix(sample(1:2, 5*5, replace=TRUE), 5, 5)
conn
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    2    2    1    2    1
# [2,]    1    1    2    2    1
# [3,]    2    2    1    2    1
# [4,]    2    2    2    2    1
# [5,]    1    1    2    2    1
```

The results:

```
f1(conn)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    2    2    1    2    1
# [2,]    1    0    1    1    0
# [3,]    2    1    0    0    1
# [4,]    2    1    0    1    0
# [5,]    1    0    1    0    1

identical(f1(conn), f2(conn))
# [1] TRUE
```

A bigger example, with time comparison:

```
set.seed(12345678)
conn <- matrix(sample(1:2, 1000*1000, replace=TRUE), 1000, 1000)

system.time(a1 <- f1(conn))
# user  system elapsed 
# 59.840   0.000  57.094 

system.time(a2 <- f2(conn))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.844   0.000   0.950 

identical(a1, a2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Maybe not the fastest method you can get (I have no doubt other people here can find much faster using e.g. compiler or Rcpp), but short and fast enough for you I hope.

---

Edit: since it has been pointed out (from the context of where this code was pulled from) that `conn` is a symmetric matrix, my solution can be shortened a bit:

```
f2 <- function(conn) {
   matches <- outer(conn[-1,1], conn[1,-1],
                    function(i,j)ifelse(i==0, FALSE, i==j)) 
   conn[-1,-1] <- as.numeric(matches)
   return(conn)
}
```

Comment: The last (oh so elegant) version crashes my machine, but the other one works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Several things come to mind.

First, you can cut the time about in half by only looping through the entries below the diagonal or above the diagonal.  If the matrix is square either will work.  If `dim(conn)[1] > dim(conn)[2]` then you'll want to loop through the bottom-left triangle using something like

```
for (j in 2:dim(conn)[2]) {
  for (i in j:dim(conn)[1]) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Second, one might try to use `apply` and it's ilk because they usually generate significant time decreases.  However, in this case each [i,j] cell refers back to both the column head `[1,j]` and the row head `[i,1]`, which means we can't just send a cell, row or column to *pply.  For code clarity, I would probably keep the `for` loops. Any *pply-based trick that worked would be so clever that I'd forget how it worked a year from now.

Finally, this seems like a classic example of something that would be much, much faster using C called from R.  This might seem like a lot of work, but it's a lot easier than you might think, even (for this particular example) if you don't know C.  The first brief example of calling C from R that made sense to me was [here](http://cran.wustl.edu/doc/contrib/Robinson-icebreaker.pdf#page=152), but it doesn't leverage Rcpp, so I wouldn't stop there.  Alternatively, if you start with *any* simple example of working Rcpp code then you could modify it to do what you want here.  If you just want to modify someone else's code, start with [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154383/converting-loop-from-r-to-c-using-rcpp).