# Speed of Daisy Function

Tags: r, performance, similarity, r-daisy

I'm working on improving the speed of a function (for a dissimilarity measure) I'm writing which is quite similar mathematically to the Euclidean distance function. However, when I time my function compared to that implemented in the `daisy` function from the `cluster` package, I find quite a significant difference in speed, with `daisy` performing much better. Given that (I'm assuming) a dissimilarity measure would require `O(n x p)` time due to the need to compare each object to itself over all variables (where `n` is number of objects and `p` is number of variables), I find it difficult to understand how the daisy function performs so well (near constant time, from the few experiments I've done) relative to my simple and direct implementation. I present the code I have used both to implement and test below. I have tried looking through the `r` source code for the implementation of the `daisy` function, but I found it difficult to understand. I found no nested `for` loop. Any help with understanding why this function performs so fast and how I could possibly modify my code to have similar speed would be very highly appreciated.

```
euclidean <- function (df){
  
  no_obj <- nrow(df)
  
  dist <- array(0, dim = c(no_obj, no_obj))
  
  for (i in 1:no_obj){
    for (j in 1:no_obj){
      dist_v <- 0
      if(i != j){
        for (v in 1:ncol(df)){
          dist_v <- dist_v + sqrt((df[i,v] - df[j,v])^2)
        }
      }
      dist[i,j] <- dist_v
    }
  }
  return(dist)
}

data("iris")

tic <- Sys.time()
dst <- euclidean(iris[,1:4])
time <- difftime(Sys.time(), tic, units = "secs")[[1]]
print(paste("Time taken [Euclidean]: ", time))

tic <- Sys.time()
dst <- daisy(iris[,1:4])
time <- difftime(Sys.time(), tic, units = "secs")[[1]]
print(paste("Time taken [Daisy]: ", time))
```

Comment: Not an expert, but based on the [source code](https://github.com/cran/cluster/blob/master/R/daisy.q) the 'number crunching' is done using a fortran subroutine. I don't know if the method uses a nested for loop (I haven't learned fortran yet), but the use of a lower-level language can result in a significantly faster run time. If you want to increase the speed of your code, two 
potential options are: vectorise it (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728137/r-is-it-possible-to-vectorise-speed-up-this-double-loop), or use a lower level language (C/C++/fortran) to do the 'heavy lifting'.

Comment: I'm also getting "NULL" returned by your function - is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: @jared_mamrot Oh, thanks a lot for this. I saw the fortran-y thing, but couldn't really understand any of it. I'm checking out the vectorization option now.

And thanks for pointing out that I forgot to return `dist`, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option:

```
 euclidean3 <- function(df) {
  require(data.table)
  n <- nrow(df)
  i <- CJ(1:n, 1:n) # generate all row combinations
  dl <- sapply(df, function(x) sqrt((x[i[[1]]] - x[i[[2]]])^2)) # loop over columns
  dv <- rowSums(dl) # sum values of columns
  d <- matrix(dv, n, n) # fill in matrix
  d
}
dst3 <- euclidean3(iris[,1:4])
all.equal(euclidean(iris[,1:4]), dst3) # TRUE

[1] "Time taken [Euclidean3]:  0.008"
[1] "Time taken [Daisy]:  0.002"
```

Largest bottleneck in your code is selecting `data.frame` elements in loop (`df[j,v])`). Maybe changing it to `matrix` also could improver speed. I believe there could be more performant approach on stackoverflow, you just need to search by correct keywords...

Comment: Thanks so much for this, @minem! This is what I was looking for, though it appears to me that if I'm able to drop to FORTRAN or C/C++, even greater speed improvement can be made. I tried converting to matrix, but dramatically increased the running time. I think the process of converting to a matrix (using `as.matrix`) is not that trivial.